# Seperate Configuration files for each user in codeigniter 

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, config

is it possible to make Config files for each and every users?

Currently i have a Config file named Siteconfig.php for global configuration.

Now a user registered,so that i need a configuration file for that user.

I have a BANNER ,user uploads images to the server and select some images for that banner.

I want to store the names of the images in the configuration file,i know that database is another way.

is there any wrong with this ? or is it possible to do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a database..

Making config files for each user means you will have to create one entry for each user. managing them them, loading them, reading them, writing them from your code etc will be difficult (you will be making your life difficult in the long run).

Comment: `managing them them, loading them, reading them, writing them from your code ` - This is so simple,Codeigniter is so powerful here,but its look like this is a nasty way,let me try DB,thank you.

Comment: As i said the in the short run you will feel it easy. But it wont be when you have like more than 100 users. Activerecord in CI is quite easy to use by the way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have a lot of data. Maybe just have one config file with a big array.

```
$user_config = array(
    // user_id = config
    1 => array(
        'banner' => 'ddfdf',
        'image' => 'gdfgdfg.png',
    )
);
```

Comment: its not possible ,ever user have so many `pages` so every pages have different configurations.So one Config file for ALL makes it Hard.

Comment: Then you should use a database. Maybe try [Redbean](http://redbeanphp.com/) is you don't like databases

Comment: Nops,no problem with DB,also its very easy to use DB,i put a suggestion here,anyway thanks for the term `Redbean`